# Bruteforce random 64character string

Tags: hash, brute-force

I've got a computer generated sha256 hash of which I need the original value.
I know the value is a random 64 character string of alphanumerical, lower and uppercase, numbers and underscores + dots.

Would it be possible in a reasonable amount of time to bruteforce this?

Comment: Open a calculator and determine how many possible 64-character alphanumeric strings are possible. I think that will give you your answer. Keep in mind that a GUID, which is simply 32 hexes, is so large that it's inconceivable to brute force all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 64 possibilities in 64 positions giving a total or 64 to the power of 64 combinations which is 3.9402006196394479212279040100143613805079739270 × 10^115
So no. Even if you had every computer on earth working on it for 1,000,000 years you still wouldn't be close

Comment: . +| for the number grater than one google ;D